# Its possible to upload a Pdf or documents file in DropBox with the using UIActivityViewController ?

Tags: ios, dropbox, uiactivityviewcontroller

Its possible to upload a Pdf or documents file in DropBox with the using UIActivityViewController like WhatsApp to file sharing ?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is download the Dropbox app and make sure it's in the list of share options. I can't say if I know it's like WhatsApp, but that's how I share to Dropbox.